# How to watch dynamic data fields in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

so i am trying to figure out whether this is possible, i am using a `prop` to dynamically name a field in `data`. So essentially i want to add a watcher to the dynamically added `data` field. Is this possible?

```
export default {
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      [this.type]: {
        place_type: "house"
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    "[this.type].place_type": function(val) {
       console.log(val);
     }
  }
}
```

Here is my attempt, but it does not work with that syntax. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: do you want to watch the property in your data object or in props?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim The prop in the data object

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve? could you explain me what you want without regarding to code